# Match serveral placeholder from string

Tags: php, regex

I used this code to extract words from a string:

```php
$code = $templates->getCode();              
$pattern = '/\(\((\w+)\)\)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $code, $matches);
```

However, this code only extracts words that either start with one parenthesis '(' or end with ')'. I want to extract the word only start with two  parentheses and end it with two . For example, if `$code` is "Hello ((name))! I'm ((age)) years old", I want to extract "name" and "age".

Comment: Check this regex101 of yours: https://regex101.com/r/lz15Jn/1 -> You were missing the g flag -> `/\(\((\w+)\)\)/g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex works. I don't know if you have looked into $matches.

```php
$code = "Hello ((name))! I'm ((age)) years old";
$pattern = '/\(\((\w+)\)\)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $code, $matches);
// $matches
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ((name))
            [1] => ((age))
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => name
            [1] => age
        )

)
```

You can also use a named group.

```php
$code = "Hello ((name))! I'm ((age)) years old";
$pattern = '/\(\((?<placeholder>\w+)\)\)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $code, $matches);
$placeholder = $matches["placeholder"] ?? [];
// $placeholder
Array
(
    [0] => name
    [1] => age
)
```